# Firebase to External Google BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I'm trying to export Firebase data to Google BigQuery using this guidance https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

It works, but my question is,
If I've already had another Google BigQuery Instance (different Project ID with Firebase)
Is it possible to direct link from Firebase to external Google BigQuery?
How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although it exports Firebase's data to a linked GCP's BigQuery account, you can set a scheduled query/transfer to another BigQuery account. Basically copying the data to another external table.

You just need to give the appropriate permissions first (ie: `BigQuery.Editor` role).